# Tracking Conversions on External Website with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, seo, event-tracking

I have a booking site that refers customers to other companies websites to confirm and pay for bookings. I only make money off of conversions, not clickthroughs. These sites are owned by other corporations and I do not have access to their website code, just to clarify.

I know that I can use GA to track clickthroughs from my site, but how do I track the actual conversions?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot track conversions on another site unless they agree to send some data back to you. That's actually the answer, but I included a bit more info below.

Your business model is that of an [affiliate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affiliate_marketing). Affiliate tracking usually works by appending an parameter to the link that goes from your website to the partner website. The partner website has to take care that your parameter is persisted throughout the booking process. Finally on the confirmation page, if your id is present, they send a beacon that informs you a booking has actually happened.

That beacon is usually an image pixel on your server; if the pixel is called it writes a line to a logfile that contains information passed via the image source (e.g. the total price if your renumeration depends on revenue). If you want you can also use Google Analytics; it is unlikely that any partner site agrees to implement fully fledged GA implementation with cross domain tracking, but you could use the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to construct a web beacon that is implemented as an image pixel that sends data back to your GA account. If you submit not only your affiliate id, but also the client id for the visit you referred to the partner site you could even attribute the conversion to the original traffic source.

But for conversion tracking you have to rely on the cooperation (and honesty) of your parters. There is no way to record transactions on their sites without some sort of tracking code.

Comment: Are there any simple tracking tools you can recommend for this scenario other than Google Analytics?